# Questões sobre Backus Naur Form

Tags: linguagens-formais

Estou com dúvida em dos exercícios sobre BNF.

1. Escreva um a BNF para gerar sequências de dígitos binários aos pares
   contiguamente, como, por exemplo: 0 0 11 0 0, 11 00 1 1 , 1 1 0 0 1 1
2. Escreva um a BNF para gerar sequências que possuam um digito seguid o
   exatamente de uma letra maiúscula , como, por exemplo 1 A , 2 B , 4 A , 3 C , 1 A , 2 B

Comment: Veja: [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/70)

Answer (score 1):

BNF nada mais é que uma notação glorificada para produções de gramáticas formais, muitas vezes usadas para gramáticas livres de contexto. Ela tem suas peculiaridades, que são:

1. não-terminais são denotados por `<angle braces>`, sendo que `<a>` equivale ao não-terminal `a` da gramática em questão (os *angle braces* são meros indicadores sintáticos)
2. terminais são denotados por `"aspas"`; eles podem ser uma sequência de terminais, então `"banana"` consiste de um terminal de comprimento 6
3. existe a palavra vazia, que alguns autores de gramáticas formais na parte mais matemática da coisa denotam por ε ou λ, aqui devorada por `""`
4. a produção é indicada por `::=`, onde o lado esquerdo gera o direito
5. se o não-terminal possuir produções alternativas, elas são indicadas por uma barra vertical `|` (não vi nada proibindo repetir o lado esquerdo da produção, então isso aqui é mais por concisão de notação)
6. qualquer possibilidade de concatenação de símbolos terminais/não-terminais pode ser feito usando espaços, por exemplo `<pré-nome> " de " <sobrenome>`
7. uma produção por linha

Dito isso, como exercício, vou deixar ao leitor a responsabilidade de transformar a notação informal de gramática que vou usar aqui para BNF formal.

Para o primeiro exemplo, podemos usar as seguintes produções:

```
S -> PAR S
S -> PAR
PAR -> "00"
PAR -> "11"
```

Não sei se a palavra vazia é aceita na linguagem, se for, basta trocar a produção `S -> PAR` para `S -> ""`.

Note aqui como as produções de `S` geram sempre concatenações de `PAR`, e `PAR` só pode gerar `"00"` ou `"11"`.

A segunda, por sua vez, é mais simples:

```
S -> DÍGITO MAIÚSCULA
```

Não vou escrever as 10 produções para `DÍGITO` nem as 26 para `MAIÚSCULA` por questões de praticidade, e que você, leitor, entendeu o ponto da resposta.

---

Por sinal, apesar de eu ter escrito usando produções livres de contexto, ambas as linguagens são regulares. Dá um pouco mais de trabalho escrever usando apenas as produções regulares a direita (o terminal ficando do lado esquerdo e o não-terminal do direito), mas são trivialmente transformadas em gramáticas regulares.